# Android onAttach - Passing value from JSON data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a JSON data to be parsed by JSON request in a **ListFragment A**. That did well. This is how part of my JSON look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "Accessories",
    "slug": "accessories",
    "count": "630",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": "371",
        "name": "Belt",
        "slug": "belt",
        "count": "15"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Right now, I'm trying to make another **ListFragment B** that shows the detail of category. So I have to pass the `id` from this JSON to ListFragment B.

I'm using an interface to communicate between fragments. I've done that as well.

The problem is how do I pull out the `id` and attach it to the main activity to be used in ListFragment B?

This is the code snippet when an item in A is pressed. I'm passing a String variable to main activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        mListener = (OnCategorySelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "Must implement OnCategorySelectedListener");
    }
};

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "category id: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String category_id = id+"";
    mListener.onCategorySelected(category_id);
}
```

Above is just an example to see if it works. This is a method I used for parsing JSON (using Volley):

```
private void parseJSON(JSONArray json) {
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            // JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject("value");
            // JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CHILD);
            // categories = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject category = json.getJSONObject(i);

                CategoryModel cm = new CategoryModel();
                // cm.setTitle(category.optString(TAG_TITLE));
                // cm.setCount(category.optString(TAG_COUNT));
                cm.setCategoryId(category
                        .getString(Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_ID));
                cm.setTitle(category
                        .getString(Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_TITLE));
                cm.setCount(category
                        .getString(Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_COUNT));

                arrCategory.add(cm);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Categories: ", "null");
    }
}
```

How do I get the CATEGORY_ID and put it in a String variable? If I create a String variable in the loop, it will only store the last value of the id. How do make so that it stores the id correspondingly to the item in the list? I hope that makes sense.

Please let me know if anything confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry but, what do you mean by one list?

Comment: So just access the relevant JSON object from the array instead of doing of iterating on all of them.

Comment: The loop is to store the item in a listview through an adapter. If doing what you said, then how am I gonna be able to get the right ID if an item was pressed?

Comment: So I assume you are passing this `ArrayList` to an `ArrayAdapter`? In that case either override the `getItemId()` method on the adapter implementation to return the relevant id, which will be passed on in the `onListItemClick()` parameter, or you can access the `CategoryModel` object from the adapter by calling `l.getItemAtPosition(position)`.

Comment: Does that mean I have to create an invisible textview for the id, and use `getItemId()` to pass it?

Comment: I didn't say anything about a `TextView`; just pass the JSON object id from the `getItemId()` method.

Comment: `getItemId()` returns `getItem(i).hashCode();`. It doesn't take the id I wanted from the JSON value, instead a hash code from the listview position. Excuse me for my noobishness.

Comment: If your JSON object id is unique, then you should use that instead; it would be easier and more useful. Change it to return `getItem(position).getCategoryId()`.

Comment: But in Category Model I've set the category id to type String. Would it be possible to get the id even though the `getItemId` must return in `long` type?

Comment: You can either change the type to `long` in your model, or you can parse the long value from the `String` with the `Long.parseLong()` method.